# Google Maps Utils IconGenerator text styles and background

Tags: java, android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I just started using Google Maps Utils library so that I can have markers with text in them. I understand the library so far and I'm successfully using it. Code snippet:

```
IconGenerator icnGenerator = new IconGenerator(this);
Bitmap iconBitmap = icnGenerator.makeIcon(item.placeItemName);

    myPlaceItemMarkers.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(item.latitude, item.longitude))
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(iconBitmap)).anchor(0.5f, 0.6f)));
```

Now I started playing around with styling the window a bit and there are two functions that interest me in particular:

```
icnGenerator.setBackground(Drawable background);
icnGenerator.setTextAppearance(int resid);
```

I looked up for info on [docs](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/) and there's only info for *BubbleIconFactory* which is deprecated. Could someone tell me how to use these 2 functions? I know **setTextAppearance** is for changing text style but how do I do it? And if I'm not wrong **setBackground** is for setting custom marker background, but I don't know how to use that either.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'm still not completely sure how to use *setBackground()* because I tried using Drawables but it wouldn't work but I figured out how to use *setTextAppearance()*.

I just made a new style:

```
<style name="iconGenText">
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
</style>
```

And then applied it to IconGenerator:

```
IconGenerator icnGenerator = new IconGenerator(this);
icnGenerator.setTextAppearance(R.style.iconGenText);
```

It works as it should.

Answer (score 8):

Set the background like this:

```
IconGenerator icnGenerator = new IconGenerator(this);
icnGenerator.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker_background));
```

marker_background has to be a .9.png file. Like the [drawables of the library](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/tree/master/library/res/drawable-xhdpi).

It works pretty good for me.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky marker_background is the background you want to set for the marker. And it's important to be a . 9.png file, so that android scales it correctly. Just have a look at the drawables of the library I have linked above.

Answer (score 0):

if you're just wanting to change away from the default marker styling without getting fancy you can do this.

```java
icnGenerator.setStyle(IconGenerator.STYLE_BLUE)
```

There's currently 7 basic styles to select from:

```
IconGenerator.STYLE_BLUE 
IconGenerator.STYLE_DEFAULT 
IconGenerator.STYLE_GREEN 
IconGenerator.STYLE_ORANGE 
IconGenerator.STYLE_PURPLE 
IconGenerator.STYLE_RED 
IconGenerator.STYLE_WHITE
```

doc: https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.maps.android/android-maps-utils/latest/com/google/maps/android/ui/IconGenerator.html